# Vector Perpendicular to a Point

Tags: java, vector, 2d

I need to calculate the vector perpendicular between two points.

[image]
I can get the original vector like this:

```
    dir.x  = point2.x - point1.x;
    dir.y  = point2.y - point1.y;
    float hyp   = (float) Math.sqrt(dir.x*dir.x + dir.y*dir.y);

    if(hyp != 0){
        dir.x /= hyp;
        dir.y /= hyp;

    }
```

But I'm not sure how to get the perpendicular vector.

Comment: So point 1,2 is `A`,`B` from the image and you want to get either of the reds?

Comment: You have calculated the length AB, not the vector.

Comment: I need both, but I assume they are negative and positive of each other?

Comment: I need the direction, or vector, not the length

Comment: A vector has a length (magnitude)

Comment: I need it normalized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flip x and y, make one of them negative, then divide by the length to normalize:

```
double x1 = y;
double y1 = -x;
double length1 = Math.sqrt(x1*x1 + y1*y1);
x1 /= length1;
y1 /= length1;
```

and to get the perpendicular point in the opposite direction:

```
double x2 = -y;
double y2 = x;
double length2 = Math.sqrt(x2*x2 + y2*y2);
x2 /= length2;
y2 /= length2;
```

You should also check if the length is non zero.

Answer (score 0):

When working in two dimensions you can get the perpendicular vector simply by switching the x and y coordinates of the other vector and negating one. This can be proven by taking the 2D rotation by 90 degrees and noting that the sines are 1 and cosines 0 so the values just switch places.

Comment: If the vector is (1,1) and you switch coordinates, the resulting vector is obviously not perpendicular. You also need to invert one coordinate.

Comment: @FrankPuffer Yep, exactly. Messed up sine and cosine already and forgot the sign.